# Get part of specific length of allocated memory space

Tags: c, malloc, allocation

I have some billions of bits loaded into RAM by the use of `malloc()` - will call it **big_set**. I also have another amount of bits (will call it **small_set**) in RAM which are all set to 1 and I know its size (how many bits - I will call it **ss_size**), but can't predict it, as varies on each execution. **ss_size** can be sometimes as small as 100 or large as hundreds of millions.

I need to do some bitwise operations between **small_set** and some *unpredictable* parts of **big_set** of **ss_size** bits length. I can't just extend **small_set** with zeros on both most-significant and least-significant sides to make its size equal **big_set**'s size, as that would be very RAM and CPU expensive (same operations will be done at same time with a lot of differently sized **small_set**s and also will do shift operations over **small_set**, expanding it would lead in much more bits to CPU work on).

Example:

**big_set**: `100111001111100011000111110001100` (would be billions of bits in reality)

**small_set**: `111111`, so **ss_size** is 6. (may be an unpredictable number of bits).

I need to take 6 bits length parts of **big_set**, e.g.: `001100`, `000111`, etc. Obs.: not necessarily Nth 6 bits, it could be from 3rd to 9th bits, for instance. I don't know how can I get it.

I don't want to get a **big_set** copy with everything zeroed except the 6 bits I would be taking, like on `000000001111100000000000000000000`, as that would be also very RAM expensive.

The question is: how can I get N bits from anywhere inside **big_set**, so I can do bitwise operations between they and **small_set**? Being N = **ss_size**.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I see that problem is not in the way of storing `small_set` in the memory, but in the implementation of required operation (bitwise operations between `small_set` and `big_set`). Do you already write some code for OR, AND, XOR and other operations?

Comment: @VolAnd I already have most of needed bitwise operations coded, but the time I wrote them I was extending `small_set` with zeros on both sides to make its size equal to `big_set`'s size. I've just noticed it was not a good idea because of large RAM usage and now I want to change it according described on question's post.

Comment: Talk about XY problems... Since small set is always a range of `1` values, the amount of useful bitwise operations is somehow limited (AND, XOR are the first I think of). Think about your actual goal (getting `N` bits out of big set, starting at position `P`) and implement it, instead of turning the problem into a bit manipulation theory.

Comment: It looks like you are asking how to access and modify substrings of a large bit string. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that the example given below will give an answer to your question, also I am not sure that the realized XOR will work correctly.

But I have tried to show how confusing can be the implementation of the algorithm, if the task is to save memory.

This is my example for case of 40 bit in `big_set` and 6 bit in `small_set`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void setBitsInMemory(uint8_t * memPtr, size_t from, size_t to)
// sets bits in the memory allocated from memPtr (pointer to the first byte)
// where from and to are numbers of bits to be set
{
    for (size_t i = from; i <= to; i++)
    {
        size_t block = i / 8;
        size_t offset = i % 8;
        *(memPtr + block) |= 0x1 << offset;
    }
}

uint8_t * allocAndBuildSmallSet(size_t bitNum)
// Allocate memory to store bitNum bits and set them to 1
{
    uint8_t * ptr = NULL;
    size_t byteNum = 1 + bitNum / 8; // determine number of bytes for  
    ptr = (uint8_t*) malloc(byteNum);
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < byteNum; i++) ptr[i] = 0;
        setBitsInMemory(ptr, 0, bitNum - 1);
    }
    return ptr;
}

void printBits(uint8_t * memPtr, size_t from, size_t to)
{
    for (size_t i = from; i <= to; i++)
    {
        size_t block = i / 8;
        size_t offset = i % 8;
        if (*(memPtr + block) & (0x1 << offset) )
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
    }
}

void applyXOR(uint8_t * mainMem, size_t start, size_t cnt, uint8_t * pattern, size_t ptrnSize)
// Applys bitwise XOR between cnt bits of mainMem and pattern 
// starting from start bit in mainMem and 0 bit in pattern
// if pattern is smaller than cnt, it will be applyed cyclically
{
    size_t ptrnBlk = 0;
    size_t ptrnOff = 0;
    for (size_t i = start; i < start + cnt; i++)
    {
        size_t block = i / 8;
        size_t offset = i % 8;
        *(mainMem + block) ^= ((*(pattern + ptrnBlk) & (0x1 << ptrnOff)) ? 1 : 0) << offset;
        ptrnOff++;
        if ((ptrnBlk * 8 + ptrnOff) >= ptrnSize)
        {
            ptrnBlk = 0;
            ptrnOff = 0;
        }
        if (ptrnOff % 8 == 0)
        {
            ptrnBlk++;
            ptrnOff = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t * big_set;
    size_t ss_size;
    uint8_t * small_set;
    big_set = (uint8_t*)malloc(5); // 5 bytes (40 bit) without initialization
    ss_size = 6;
    small_set = allocAndBuildSmallSet(ss_size);
    printf("Initial big_set:\n");
    printBits(big_set, 0, 39);
    // some operation for ss_size bits starting from 12th
    applyXOR(big_set, 12, ss_size, small_set, ss_size);
    // output for visual analysis
    printf("\nbig_set after XOR with small_set:\n");
    printBits(big_set, 0, 39);
    printf("\n");
    // free memory
    free(big_set);
    free(small_set);
}
```

At my PC I can see the following:

[image]